# Fix prettyprint for bash

Tags: bug, status-deferred, syntax-highlighting

**UPDATE**:
[issue tracked on prettyprinter github repo](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/355)

I posted a bash code a few days ago and noticed that there is an issue with the prettyprinter as I am using the bash specific built-in variable `$#` (number of arguments).
A comment in bash starts with `#`, so when the `$#` variable is used, the prettyprinter considers the code next to it on the same line as a comment while it should not.

Here is the code excerpt as image (prettyprinting did not work on meta):

[image: bash code example]

[Original code answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151377/1152843)

Comment: this is a bug that needs to be fixed on the Google Prettify end first, released as stable and then pulled and deployed by SE

Comment: Thank you, found an open issue on the subject in Google Prettify github repo, here where it is tracked https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/355